# Recording GET requests to a table from REST API

Tags: rest, http, post, get

I would like to record the various GET requests to my API in a table and use that table as part of the calculation of what to return for future GET requests.

Perhaps the easiest test example would be a GET function that returns the number of GET requests in the last hour.

The REST protocol says that GET requests should only have data returns.

Do I need to POST the request and then GET the results of the same request?

Comment: May be you only need to think of a caching mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve that with nodejs
You should have the requests saved in a json file or database for example and have another service that returns this saved data. 
Take a look at expressjs
Best luck